# The command(s) completed successfully

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have written a stored procedure given below....it should print the values I am printing using PRINT command. But rather printing these values, when I executed this procedure from Query Analyzer its shows 'The command(s) completed successfully'. Can u suggest any modification in code or other solutions

Thanks in advance... :)

```
CREATE PROCEDURE  getPullCords(@start_dt varchar(25),@end_dt varchar(25))
 AS
declare @t varchar(25),@p varchar(50),@v int
declare @mycur CURSOR

SET @mycur  =  CURSOR FAST_FORWARD
FOR
select timestamp,point_id,_val from tcf1_pullcord where timestamp between @start_dt and @end_dt

OPEN @mycur
FETCH NEXT FROM @mycur
INTO @t,@p,@v

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
PRINT @t
PRINT @p
PRINT @v
FETCH NEXT FROM @mycur
INTO @t,@p,@v
END

CLOSE @mycur
DEALLOCATE @mycur

GO
```

Comment: Are you using SQL Server Management Studio (Express)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whatever you've written to print data is correct.

However, if there is data to print then it is printing and you'll not be able to the printed data `Results` tab.

To see your printed data choose `Messages` tab of the result section.

Thanks.

Comment: hey thanks....actually i forgot that database has been changed recently. There was no data between the date range I was passing..

Answer (score 4):

Right click in Query Window > Connection > Disconnect. Then push F5 or execute; Login will display. Login. If you get an error message at first, add a `USE` statement or fix the error, then retry the above steps. Your cursor will now execute at least once and display results before you need to follow the steps again.

If you execute again during the same session you will notice the same message:

```
Command(s) completed successfully.
```

Very strange bug...

Answer (score 3):

The output from the print statement does not go to the query results window. It's been a while since I've used Query Analyzer (vs management studio), but look for a separate "Messages" tab and you should find your print output there.

Comment: Its shows this message in 'Messages' window itself....while grid window is empty....

Comment: @Dharmesh Ctrl+T will switch it into text output so they'll be no grid at all if you don't like the empty grid output. Ctrl+D will switch it back. This works in Query Analyzer and SSMS.

Answer (score 3):

Run the command:

```
select timestamp,point_id,_val from tcf1_pullcord where timestamp between @start_dt and @end_dt
```

on its own (substituting the `@start_dt` and `@end_dt` vars for the values you're testing with). Does it return any rows? If not, the procedure is never entering the while loop and printing anything.

If it does return rows, try placing a PRINT 'test' outside the loop to ensure it is behaving correctly.

Comment: Hey Thanks...YA you are absolutely right....I was entering wrong date range. No data available between these date range..

Answer (score 0):

Ran into an issue with a stored procedure printing Command(s) completed successfully instead of returning the result set and thought of the solution while viewing this thread. I'm posting in case anyone else can benefit.

My issue was the size of the parameter passed was larger than the variable I was passing it to. This was running through my stored procedure by-passing all logical arguments because it met none of the criteria.