# How to drop multiple columns in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have multiple columns

**Dbname: dbo.Test**

Column's name (example) :

```
ABC_1 | DEF_2 | GHI_3 | JKL_4 | MNO_5 | PQR_6 | STU_7
```

How can I write queries that can drop column `GHI_3` until `STU_7` using a loop?

Comment: drop columns or data in the columns? does it have any foreign key dependencies to other tables? Does it form part of the index.. a lot to consider before you go dropping columns!

Comment: @Harry drop the columns

Comment: OK.. why a loop and not on one go? you can go alter test drop column GHI_3,STU_7

Comment: @Harry this is actually the example columns. My exact data consists up to 50 columns :D That is why I want to use the loop

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to write a loop to do this, one way is using `sys.columns` table to get all the columns which you want to drop.

Let say you want to drop all columns except '`Col11`' and '`Col2`' in that case you can write your query like following.

```
declare @dropstmt as nvarchar(max) ='alter table Test  drop column ' 
                          +  stuff((select ', ' + quotename(name) 
             from   
             (
                select c.name 
                from sys.columns c
                    JOIN sys.tables t ON c.object_id = t.object_id
                where t.name = 'test'
                and c.name  not in('col1','col2')
             )t
             for xml path(''), type).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, ''); 
print @dropstmt
exec sp_executesql @dropstmt
```

Comment: When I uncomment print @dropstmt it display error "Must declare the scalar variable "@cols".

Comment: it was a typo, it should be '@dropstmt' instead of '@cols'. I have updated the answer.

Comment: It display error "Could not find stored procedure ''. @PSK

Comment: when you are getting this error? in execute statement??

Comment: I have modified the answer, can you try once

Answer (score 1):

You can use this query to delete the multiple columns from the table.

```
alter table Test
    drop column GHI_3, JKL_4, MNO_5, PQR_6, STU_7
```

Comment: Thank you but this is actually the example columns. My exact data consists up to 50 columns :D That is why I want to use the loop

Answer (score 1):

As alternative to solution on dropping the columns directly with Alter Statement , if you want to make use of loop, you can use cursor as well.

Create a test table

```
Create table testdropcols   
(Col1 varchar(20)
,col2 varchar (30)  
,col3 varchar (30) 
,col4 varchar(30) 
,col5 varchar(30) 
,col6 varchar(30) 
,col7 varchar(30)
,col8 varchar(30)
,col9 varchar(30)
,col10 varchar(30))
```

Use systables and syscolumns for current database to get all the columns for a given table, and select few columns just for test.

```
    Declare @tablename varchar(30) , @colname varchar(30), @rownum int 

DECLARE Curstest CURSOR
  for 
select Table_name,columnname,rownum from (
select  st.name as Table_name, sc.name as columnname, Row_number() over (partition by  st.name order by sc.name) rownum   from sys.tables st 
join sys.columns sc on st.object_id = sc.object_id 
where st.name = 'testdropcols'  ) z 
where z.rownum between 5 and 10  
Open Curstest 
Fetch next from Curstest into @tablename, @colname, @rownum 
while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
Begin 
declare @sql varchar(max)

set @sql = 'ALTER TABLE '+@tablename+'   Drop column  '+@colname+''

Print @sql 

Exec(@sql)

Print('Dropping column '+ @colname  + ' from ' + @tablename+ ' for rownumber ' +cast(@rownum as varchar(10))) 
Fetch next from Curstest into @tablename, @colname, @rownum 
end 

Close Curstest 
DEALLOCATE Curstest
```

With the print statement inside cursor you get the output in this way with each execution.

```
  ALTER TABLE testdropcols   Drop column  col4
Dropping column col4 from testdropcols for rownumber 5
ALTER TABLE testdropcols   Drop column  col5
Dropping column col5 from testdropcols for rownumber 6
ALTER TABLE testdropcols   Drop column  col6
Dropping column col6 from testdropcols for rownumber 7
ALTER TABLE testdropcols   Drop column  col7
Dropping column col7 from testdropcols for rownumber 8
ALTER TABLE testdropcols   Drop column  col8
Dropping column col8 from testdropcols for rownumber 9
ALTER TABLE testdropcols   Drop column  col9
Dropping column col9 from testdropcols for rownumber 10
```

If you select the testdropcols you will have the columns which did not exist in the drop statement in

```
Col1 Col2 Col3 Col10
```

Answer (score 0):

In **SQL Server**, for dropping multiple columns of a table considering columns has constraints also, this is how can you do that

```
alter table dbo.Test
    drop column GHI_3, STU_7
```

**Syntax:**

```
DROP { [ CONSTRAINT ] constraint_name | COLUMN column_name } [ ,...n ]
```

And there is no need to do this in loop, it can be done in a single statement.

Answer (score 0):

Adding this because other answers didn't actually used a loop.
I don't know how many times you would use something like this though...
It surely can be improved

```
USE Dbname;
go
CREATE PROCEDURE DeleteColumnRange
    @table_name varchar(100),
    @first varchar(100),
    @last varchar(100)
AS   
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    declare @range_start int
    declare @range_end int

    SELECT ORDINAL_POSITION, COLUMN_NAME INTO #columns_to_delete
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE @table_name

    set @range_start = (SELECT ORDINAL_POSITION
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE @table_name AND COLUMN_NAME LIKE @first)

    set @range_end = (SELECT ORDINAL_POSITION
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE @table_name AND COLUMN_NAME LIKE @last)

    DECLARE @result NVARCHAR(max)

    IF @range_end > @range_start
        DECLARE @cnt INT = @range_start

        WHILE @cnt < @range_end
        BEGIN
            SET @cnt = @cnt + 1
            SET @result = (SELECT COLUMN_NAME from #columns_to_delete where ORDINAL_POSITION = @cnt)
            print ('ALTER TABLE ' + @table_name + ' DROP COLUMN ' + @result)
        END;
GO
```

Usage:

```
DeleteColumnRange @table_name = 'Test', @first = 'GHI_3', @last = 'STU_7'
```

Returns:

```
ALTER TABLE Test DROP COLUMN JKL_4
ALTER TABLE Test DROP COLUMN MNO_5
ALTER TABLE Test DROP COLUMN PQR_6
```

Just copy and execute, safer than dropping columns.

Comment: I try to use the DeleteColumnRange procedure, it shows "Commands completed successfully". But when I try to SELECT* the table, there is nothing change. Is there something I've missed? @Rasnick

Comment: Check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8395245/the-commands-completed-successfully also, did you create the SP in the correct DB? Are you calling the SP from the correct DB with the correct table name and column names? I just checked it and it works fine for any number of columns

Answer (score 0):

I have provided a sample script to delete a list of columns from a table. You don't need a loop, as you can delete multiple columns in a single `DROP COLUMN` statement.

```
USE tempdb
go

CREATE TABLE dbo.test(a int, b int, c int)

DECLARE @TableName SYSNAME = N'dbo.test' -- table holding columns to drop
DECLARE @ColumnNames NVARCHAR(4000) = N'b,c' -- columns to drop
DECLARE @sqlDropColumnStmt NVARCHAR(4000)
SET @sqlDropColumnStmt = N'ALTER TABLE ' + @TableName + N' DROP COLUMN ' + @ColumnNames;
EXEC(@sqlDropColumnStmt)
```